# Tibco Spotfire Analyst 10.10.5 LTS - Expression for a KPI

Tags: expression, spotfire, tibco

Newb here, so please be kind.

I have a product that we receive and evaluate sessions against our rules engine.  Some sessions may have multiple rules that are evaluated, which are recorded as separate records with the same session ID.
In our analytics we consider that if a single session is evaluated against 6 rules, and any rule fails, then that session is considered a "Fail".

There is an associated cost of the service that is being evaluated which is imported value from the database.
For example, service code 123 has a cost associated as $10.50, each rule/record that gets evaluated against that service code will have a column value of cost as $10.50.

I have a KPI in my report that I want to record only the unique sessions that failed and calculate the associated cost as a "Savings Opportunity"; without cacluating each record that may have the same session ID.

In this below example, I have 2 unique session ids for the same service code.  One "Failed" and one passed.   I want to write an expression for the KPI that would only count a single Cost of the unique session id that failed. (should be $10.50)

I believe the expression for that KPI would be something similar to this, but unsure?

Any suggestions?
[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxgK8.png)

Sum(If([Test Status]="Fail",If[ UniqueID], [Service Cost]as [ Savings Opportunity]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think KPI charts work with IF and OVER expressions, so I would suggest to use the *Limit data using expression* functionality
to only feed the desired rows into the KPI calculation.

1. in your KPI Settings, Data tab,  set the Limit data using expression as:

   [Test Status]='Fail' and DenseRank(RowId(),[Session ID])=1

this would capture only failed sessions, and only the first item of each session.

3. then for your KPI Values you can simply use the custom expression:

   Sum([Service Cost]) as [Savings Opportunity]

(Your example would benefit from being more general, to help testing solutions. It could be improved if you added another failed session id,
with or without the same Service Cost.
Also I think there is a typo as the first B row is a Fail but
you say a session is either a Fail or a Pass).

Comment: I had to do some slight edits to fold in another condition, so with slight tweaks I think this solution will work for me!   Thanks a million!!  Really appreciate it.